# Fun combinatorics: How many numbers with some restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

I came accross this fun problem today: How many 8-digit numbers are there where:

- each digit appears only one
- digits 1-4 appear sequentially (though not necessarily consecutively)
- 5 does not appear after 4

I basically counted all possibilities but what would be a nice way to express the solution? Thank you.

Comment: You could count the number of permutations of $[8]$ where 1-4 appear consecutively, and subtract the number of permutations where 1-5 appear consecutively.

Comment: Do you mean $5$ appears nowhere after $4$, or $5$ doesn't appear immediately after $4$?

Comment: @Jared: nowhere after 4.

Comment: @vadim123: not sure I understand why.

Comment: I assume you don't allow $0$ digit at the first digit?

Comment: @user1377000 the permutations where 1-5 appear sequentially are necessarily a subset of the permutations where 1-4 appear sequentially. they are also precisely those which you do not want to include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the suggestion in the hint, we compute the number of ways $1-4$ appear consecutively, and subtract the number of ways $1-5$ appear consecutively.  We split into two cases.

Case 1: The first digit is $1$.  Then, choose the slots for $2,3$, and $4$, and arrange other numbers to fill in.  Here we find:

$$\binom{7}{3}\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3=12600$$

ways to do this.  To find how many of these arrangements have $5$ after $4$, choose the $4$ slots for $2,3,4$, and $5$, and arrange other numbers to fill in.  There are

$$\binom{7}{4}\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3=2100$$

ways to do this, so in case 1, we find $10500$ ways total.

Case 2: The first digit is not $1$.  Then, choose the four slots for the numbers $1,2,3,$ and $4$, and fill in the remaining numbers, remembering $0$ can't be the first digit.  There are:

$$\binom{7}{4}\cdot5\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3=10500$$

ways to do this.  To find how many of these arrangements have $5$ after $4$, choose the $5$ slots for $1,2,3,4$, and $5$, and fill in the remaining slots without $0$ in the first slot:

$$\binom{7}{5}\cdot4\cdot4\cdot3=1008$$

So from case 2 we find $9492$ ways as well.

In all, there are $19,992$ such numbers.